# Looking for a specific device to secure a pick to your hand

Tags: guitar, picks

Some years ago, I was chatting with the gutarist in a cafe in Cape May, New Jersey, and I asked him how he switched between flatpicking and fingerstyle playing so smoothly. He had a little gadget that secured a pick to a short piece of rubber attached to his ring finger. It held it tightly enough that it didn't get in his way while playing fingerstyle passages, but loosely enough to grab it and use it.

I've never seen one of these devices since; it may have been homemade. Has anyone seen one of these? Where did you get it? Failing that, how can I make one of these?

I'm wall aware of pick holders of all sorts, and my current favorite is one that holds a pick or two to the headstock, but something like this would be wonderfully useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess these are what You are looking for...
The JAmKat or the Flip

Never tried them myself as I keep the pick under the scratchboard....

[Jam Kat](http://www.krikawa.com/jewelry/body-of-work/styles2.aspx?tag=214)

[Flip!](http://www.pick-smith.com/media.html)

EDIT:
I stumbled upon [another  little device today...](http://accessories.musiciansfriend.com/product/ZeroGravity-Orbit-Guitar-Pick?sku=110100)

Comment: Nice; not quite the device I saw, but very close in functionality. I keep a pick under the pickguard as well on my electric, I wish that were a feasible option on my acoustic!

Comment: Oh, I was almost certain it was the Jam Kat, it fitted your description perfectly... They seem a bit expensive though, compared to keeping your pick between your teeth..

Comment: The Jam Kat might work if nobody can come up with the exact device. The fact that you can use it while writing is a plus. (i.e., it's good for songwriting or transcription work.)

Comment: The Jam Kat arrived today, and it's a very nice gadget, it's very easy to use. Unfortunately, I find that changing the angle of the pick pops it out of the holder. Perhaps there's something that can be done to correct this; I've emailed the manufacturer. But for playing straightforward rhythm, it's a clever device and I recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like  [Gorilla snot](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&safe=active&q=gorilla+snot&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&wrapid=tlif130019061696310&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=9429186803840495683&sa=X&ei=N1Z_TajDDc650QGbnIHxCA&ved=0CCsQ8wIwAg). It's basically a glue that guitar players use to hold their pick. I've used some before, and I thought it was pretty good. It also washes right off.

Comment: Well, yes and no. I understand Gorilla Snot as being there to keep the pick between your fingers. I'd think that 1), using GS here would make it harder to get the pick off your fingers and get in the way of fingerpicking, and 2) if you put it on the back of your fingers or your palm, it might work.

Answer (score 1):

Mention of gorilla snot sounds nicely off-topic, which I take as license to mention my own fix for slippery plectra.

I use skateboard anti-slip sheeting (basically a fine black sandpaper, but weatherproof and with an adhesive backing).

It's surprisingly thin, can be trimmed to the size and shape of the grip end of the plectrum, and -put on both sides- provides all the traction you need for truly ballistic rhythm guitar. The working end of the plectrum retains all it's flexibility and clarity, so there are only benefits where tone, accuracy and speed are concerned.

Moreover, I've yet to see any plectrum take off into the void following this treatment.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[I have a way](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/how-to-hide-a-flat-pick-in-the-right-hand-when-switching-to-finger-picking-warre/1230#1230) to hold onto the pick when I fingerpick. Hardware would just get in my way. I also have two or three picks stuck under my pickguard in case I drop one. I haven't seen anything like that, and I suspect that the back pages of Acoustic Guitar or Guitar Player would have one of those. So, I suspect it's his own invention.

(Would have commented instead of answered, because "I never heard of it" is not much of an answer, but otherwise, no link.)

Answer (score 0):

There are picks designed for finger-picking

[Alaska Pik Finger Guitar Pick](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Alaska-Pik-Finger-Guitar-Pick-110630-i1123794.gc)

[Ernie Ball Thumb Picks](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Ernie-Ball-Thumb-Picks-105633051-i1123913.gc)

Both are designed to stay on your fingers.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No, as I said, I'm looking for a device to secure a conventional pick. I've tried fingerpicks and thumbpicks, and I can get a better sound and be more accurate with conventional picks. But I keep trying these every few years anyway!